# How to correctly stop a storyboard declared programmatically

Tags: wpf, wpf-animation

I've a WPF application that performs a cell blink when a value in the datasource has been updated and it works fine.

I've noticed profiling the application that when I perform the update really fast the memory is growing. Since I start the storyboard in this way

```
 private static DoubleAnimation blink =
        new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = 0,
            To = 1,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2),
            FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop
        };
 private void Items_ItemChanged(object sender, ItemChangedEventArgs<ExpandoObject> e)
    {
       var club = e.Item;
       var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(club) as Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewRow;
       if (row != null)
       {
          var column = grid.Columns[e.PropertyName];
          var cell = row.Cells.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Column == column);
          if (cell != null)   //In case of virtualization I won't have all the columns
          {
              Storyboard.SetTarget(blink, cell.Content as TextBlock);
              Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(blink, new PropertyPath(Button.OpacityProperty));
              var sb = new Storyboard();
              sb.Children.Add(blink);
              sb.Begin();
          }
       }
    }
```

I suspect I've to stop the animation but I don't know how I 've to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out `Storyboard` from `Items_ItemChanged`.

```
    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    private void Items_ItemChanged(object sender, ItemChangedEventArgs<ExpandoObject> e)
    {
        sb.Stop();
        sb.Children.Clear();

        sb.Children.Add(blink);

        var club = e.Item;
        var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(club) as Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewRow;
        if (row != null)
        {
            var column = grid.Columns[e.PropertyName];
            var cell = row.Cells.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Column == column);
            if (cell != null)   //In case of virtualization I won't have all the columns
            {
                Storyboard.SetTarget(blink, cell.Content as TextBlock);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(blink, new PropertyPath(Button.OpacityProperty));

                sb.Begin();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this way I can stop it somehow or it's just fine?

Comment: @advapi check and tell

Comment: You're great no more memory growing!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are creating a new storyboard each time the item changes rather than reusing an existing one:

```
var sb = new Storyboard();
```

If you really must do this then you need to handle the storyboard finished event and remove it from the cell.